# Не принимается уведомление onCharacteristicRead при программировании в среде Android Studio

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Я написал в среде Android Studio программу, которая при помощи протокола Bluetooth Low Energy записывает некоторую строку в одну характеристику периферийного устройства, а затем читает эхо из другой характеристики.

Принимается уведомление onCharacteristicWrite после записи строки в характеристику, уведомление onCharacteristicChanged. А после обращения к функции readCharacteristic уведомление onCharacteristicRead не принимается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем здесь причина.